# Can't get Zurb Foundation accordion to work

Tags: javascript, zurb-foundation, accordion

I'm using Zurb's Foundation, attempting to build a FAQ page using the accordion js. But it's not working and I have no idea why. All the js files are in the js folder. Here's my whole page:

```
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
<script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="row row-padding">
   <div class="small-12 columns"> 
    <h1>FAQ:<h1>
    </div>
 </div> 


<div class="row row-padding small-12">
    <ul class="accordion" data-accordion>
        <li class="accordion-navigation">
            <a href="#panel13a">Question</a>
            <div id="panel13a" class="content">
            Answer
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>    
<script>
$('#myAccordionGroup').on('toggled', function (event, accordion) {
console.log(accordion);
});
</script>
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.accordion.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm brand new to HTML websites, so sorry if it's something stupid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are targeting your accordion with an `id` that doesn't exist in your HTML.

You'll need to add the `id` to your HTML like this:

```
<div class="row row-padding small-12">
    <ul id="myAccordionGroup" class="accordion" data-accordion>
        <li class="accordion-navigation">
            <a href="#panel13a">Question</a>
            <div id="panel13a" class="content">
            Answer
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Also change the order of your scripts so that your custom accordion loads after everything else.

```
<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.accordion.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).foundation();
$('#myAccordionGroup').on('toggled', function (event, accordion) {
  console.log(accordion);
});
</script>
```

Here is a working CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jPmRyB

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about $(document).foundation();

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html - Initialize Foundation